# How I can skip the error in excel file when i use it ti send messages to the customers from excel to whatsapp?

Tags: excel, contacts, whatsapp

I want to send messages via Whatsapp by Excel to my customers, but I have some error numbers, so I want the code to skip these error numbers without stopping the code

```
Sub send()
Dim contact As String
Dim text As String
u = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("whatsapp").Range("a:a")) - 2
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://web.whatsapp.com/
​"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:12​"))
For I = 0 To u
contact = Sheets("whatsapp").Range("a2").Offset(I, 0).Value
text = Sheets("whatsapp").Range("i2").Offset(I, 0).Value
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05​"))
Call SendKeys(contact, True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05​"))
Call SendKeys("~", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05​"))
Call SendKeys(text, True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01​"))
Call SendKeys("~", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01​"))
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I would never in my right mind use `SendKeys` if a customer was remotely involved. It's unreliable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel/VBA: Skip error and continue w/ code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686701/excel-vba-skip-error-and-continue-w-code-execution)